# App can't Navigate to Page1 ('MainPage does not contain a definition for 'RootFrame_OnNavigated' and no accessible...)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've tried searching for solutions and couldn't find any accurate ones. I keep getting the same error when launching my UWP/XAML app:

> CS1061  'MainPage' does not contain a definition for
> 'RootFrame_OnNavigated' and no accessible extension method
> 'RootFrame_OnNavigated' accepting a first argument of type 'MainPage'
> could be found

I've gone through the documentation and changed

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

to

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1), e.Arguments);
```

in order to specify Page1 in the call to Frame.Navigate instead of MainPage.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages)

Here is the code in MainPage.xaml:

```
    <muxc:NavigationView x:Name="NavigationViewControl"
        IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False"            
        IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"           
        Header="Home" 
        DisplayModeChanged="NavigationViewControl_DisplayModeChanged"
        SelectionFollowsFocus="Enabled"
        ItemInvoked="NavigationView_OnItemInvoked"
        PaneDisplayMode="Auto"
        Canvas.ZIndex="0">
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" x:Name="Menu1Item" Tag="Page1"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Contact" Content="Account" x:Name="Menu2Item" Tag="Page2"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Bullets" Content="Absences" x:Name="Menu3Item" Tag="Page3"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Library" Content="Grades" x:Name="Menu4Item" Tag="Page4"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Flag" Content="Grad Reqs" x:Name="Menu5Item" Tag="Page5"/>
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Grid Padding="20">
            <Frame x:Name="rootFrame" Navigated="RootFrame_OnNavigated"/>
        </Grid>
    </muxc:NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void NavigationView_OnItemInvoked(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args) {
    FrameNavigationOptions navOptions = new FrameNavigationOptions();
    navOptions.TransitionInfoOverride = args.RecommendedNavigationTransitionInfo;

    string navItemTag = args.InvokedItemContainer.Tag.ToString();

    Type pageType = null;
    if (navItemTag == "Page1") {
        pageType = typeof (Page1);
    } else if (navItemTag == "Page2") {
        pageType = typeof (Page2);
    } else if (navItemTag == "Page3") {
        pageType = typeof (Page3);
    }

    if (pageType == null) {
        return;
    }

    rootFrame.NavigateToType(pageType, null, navOptions);
}
```

I don't see any missing references or definitions so I'm confused. I made sure spelling and casing was correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsVDJ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, it means that you've declared an event handler for the [Frame.Navigated event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-22621). But the compiler doesn't find that event handler in the **MainPage.xaml.cs**. So you are getting this error.

**How to solve it**

Option one, if you are not trying to handle the event, the easiest way is to change the code of the `Frame` like this:

```
<Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>
```

Option two, if you want to handle this event, you will need to add the event handler in the **MainPage.xaml.cs** like this:

```
  private void RootFrame_OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```